# Merge excel files from 2 folders with output to another folder

Tags: python, excel

i have 3 xlsx files in 2 subfolders of main folder. is there a way in python to take check same name files from both folders and combine into new excel file with outputs from both in different tabs (tab names should be folder name)

Input:

```
Desktop\main_folder\folder_a\test1.xlsx  
Desktop\main_folder\folder_a\test2.xlsx  
Desktop\main_folder\folder_a\test3.xlsx

Desktop\main_folder\folder_b\test1.xlsx  
Desktop\main_folder\folder_b\test2.xlsx  
Desktop\main_folder\folder_b\test3.xlsx
```

Output:

```
Desktop\main_folder\folder_c\test1.xlsx
```

(sheet 1 : data from folder a [sheet name folder_a])
(sheet 2 : data from folder b [sheet name folder_b])

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsyUR.jpg)

Comment: It is possible with python. what have you tried.

Comment: i have added the code above which i tried but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `os.listdir()` to list all files in your `folder_a` and `folder_b` and collect those file names into a list. You can later create a loop to check for file name that exist in both folder. Then use Python Excel modules such as `openpyxl` or `XlsxWriter` to create new worksheet in the existing excel workbook and move the excel worksheet from another workbook to the new worksheet.

Comment: @Chirag5523 I look at your code, the yellow line seems to suggest that `xlsx` is not a valid module. Please try any of the 2 modules that I mentioned and let me know if that works or if other issues appear.